# Continue process when popup closes - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have created a Chrome extension that searches for a given word, and then repeats the search, dismissing words previously found (with the popup open). It works well but now I want to take it one step further and make it so it continues to search when the popup is closed, so I am transferring the code to a background JS file but it will no longer loop or continue after the popup is closed.

**app.html**

```
...<script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.highlight-3.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
        <p id="title">Search Keyword/Terms</p>
        <div id="fields">
        <input type="text" id="t1" placeholder="e.g. help, buy.." />
        <button class="fa fa-play" id="search_btn" ></button>
        <button class="fa fa-stop" id ="clear_btn" ></button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
function search(that) {

    var inputText = new String (t1.value);
    var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
        {code:"$(document.body).highlight('"+inputText+"','"+ bkg.random_color()+"')"});

    var searchButton = document.getElementById('search_btn');
    searchButton.style.visibility='hidden';

    var clearButton = document.getElementById('clear_btn');
    clearButton.style.visibility='visible';

    bkg.search_repeat(inputText);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

  var searchButton = document.getElementById('search_btn');
  searchButton.addEventListener('click', search);

  var clearButton = document.getElementById('clear_btn');
  clearButton.addEventListener('click', hl_clear);
  clearButton.style.visibility='hidden';

  var searchQuery = document.getElementById('t1');
  searchQuery.addEventListener('keypress', handle_keypress);

  var delimField = document.getElementById('delim');
  delimField.addEventListener('keypress', handle_keypress);
});
```

**background.js**

```
function search(that) {

    var inputText = new String (t1.value);

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
        {code:"$(document.body).highlight('"+inputText+"','"+ random_color()+"')"});

    var searchButton = document.getElementById('search_btn');
    searchButton.style.visibility='hidden';

    var clearButton = document.getElementById('clear_btn');
    clearButton.style.visibility='visible';

    setInterval(function(){ 
        async_search(inputText);
    }, 2000);
}


function search_repeat(keyword) {
    setInterval(function(){ 
        reSearch(inputText);
    }, 2000);
}

function reSearch(keyword) {

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
        {code:"$(document.body).highlight('"+keyword+"','"+random_color()+"')"});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `getBackgroundPage` you call the background pages DOM and manipulate the JS but it runs in the foreground popup. You want to add a message listener to the background page that calls the process in the background pages DOM. 
[onmessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) and [sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage)

This will do what you need.

EDIT

Foreground:

```
function search(that) {
    var inputText = new String (t1.value);
    var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
        {code:"$(document.body).highlight('"+inputText+"','"+ bkg.random_color()+"')"});

    var searchButton = document.getElementById('search_btn');
    searchButton.style.visibility='hidden';

    var clearButton = document.getElementById('clear_btn');
    clearButton.style.visibility='visible';

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            search_repeat: inputText //Send method search_repeat with param inputText

    }); 
}
```

and in the background JS:

```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(keyword) { //Start the message listener and set an action. Add 'if's here if you want more than 1.
       setInterval(function(){
            reSearch(keyword.search_repeat);
        }, 2000);
   });
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I would use it in my extension, I am new to async JS and chrome API's so finding it a bit baffling.

Comment: Just to clarify, you create one message listener. You wouldn't create one per action. You use if/switch in the 1 single listener and send different messages to trigger the conditional. You can repeat sendMessage as many times as you like.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I have used the code above but it has stopped working now

Comment: I spotted a typo - try it now

Comment: I don't the code is here if I have missed something https://github.com/Philyorkshire/Keyword-Tracker

Comment: Try the new code, should help - but no errors? Are you checking the background page for errors as well as the popup?

Comment: Sorry I placed that comment without seeing your typo message - it has worked! Thanks a lot - that has been rattling me for hours :)