# Chrome Extensions background script not working when the popup is closed

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a simple chrome extension that runs in the background. The extension works just as I want when I have the popup open. But when I close it stops to create notifications. How do I make the background.js script run in the background and not only when the user has the popup open?

```js
document.getElementById("notify").addEventListener("click", setTime);

var options = {
 type: "progress",
 title: "My first popup",
 message: "hello world",
 iconUrl: "twitter.png",
 progress: 90
};

function setTime() {
 setInterval(notify, 5000);
}

function notify() {
 chrome.notifications.create(options, function() {
  console.log("popup");
 });
}
```

```css
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "description",
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "background"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Test",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>
<p>Type your name:</p>
<input id="input-name" type="text"></input>
<button id="name-send">Send</button>
<button id="clear">Clear data</button>
<button id="notify">notify</button>
<script src="content.js"></script>
<script src="background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`"persistent": true`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)

Comment: Also, don't include background.js in your popup - those are two separate  different pages.

Comment: It still doesn´t work even though a chrome popup comes up when I start the exension telling me that the extension runs in the background. Shouldn't the extension keep creating notifications when I have closed the popup?

Comment: You may refer with this [forum](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/h48MdCS7d5Q) which stated that you need to have the pop up page defined at the HTML and a background page (also defined at the manifest) that will handle all the rest of your logic (code behind). You may also check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930070/continue-process-when-popup-closes-chrome-extension).